# Integration Oracle Salesforce via REST API

Tags: salesforce, oracle-apex

I'm developing several procedures in order to integrate our Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production with Salesforce. I successfully build it using *apex_web_service* for the request and *APEX_JSON* for parsing the response. The request for Salesforce REST API is like this (e.g. sObject GET):

```
apex_web_service.make_rest_request (
                p_url           => '/sobjects/'||SOBJECT_API_NAME||'/'||RECORD_ID'
                ,p_http_method  => 'GET'
                ,p_body         => pReqBody
                ,p_wallet_path  => lWalletPath
                ,p_https_host   => HTTPSHOST
            );
```

where SOBJECT_API_NAME , RECORD_ID ,pReqBody ,lWalletPath are parameters passed to the procedure building the request and HTTPSHOST is the value of the CommonName from the certificate of the Salesforce site after login.
I have an issue with the **p_https_host** parameter because i change it a couple of time since I begin develop the integration without problems but in the last few days the error

> ORA-24263: Certificate of the remote server does not match the target address.

is raised also changing the value accordingly with the certificate.

**** EDIT ****

The MT0's comment point me out that I miss to mention some step in setup that I have incorrectly considered implied.

On certificate change I download the crt file via browser, move it on db server and add it to the oracle wallet already created (I try also remove + create again) finally I set the value of *p_https_host* with the *Common Name* of this new certificate.

This flow has worked a couple of time but now it fails so I will appreciate some suggestion about how to "debug" or about something I am doing wrong

Comment: The error looks fairly self-explanatory "Certificate of the remote server does not match the target address." You are connecting to a HTTPS server but the URI used by the SSL certificate that host uses does not match the URI that you are passing via the `p_hhtps_host` parameter. You probably need to either use the correct `p_https_host` value or fix the SSL certificate on the remote server if you have changed its location.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Salesforce support we check the certificate and the configuration of EDGE Network and they point out that the API Client must support SNI.

Despite the Oracle documentation says:

> **https_host**
>
> A string representing the host name.
>
> If the string does not begin with a wildcard, the string will be used as the host > name for server name indication (SNI).
>
> If the string begins with a wildcard, the string will be used to match against the > common name (CN) of the remote server's certificate for an HTTPS request.
>
> If NULL, the host name in the given URL will be used for SNI.

only applying **Patch 25734963: SNI SUPPORT IN UTL_HTTP** (as suggested by the Oracle support in response of our SR) to our 12.2 version the SNI is fully supported